# MySQL configuration for running tests faster

Tags: mysql, unit-testing

I want to speed up testing web applications by configuring MySQL.

I create web applications with PHP and MySQL.  When developing, tests are run every time files are saved.  Therefore, faster execution of tests saves development time and makes me feel comfortable.

Though there are sereval ways to speed up tests, its database must be one of them.
As a testing environment, all I need is quicker response.  I don't need durability or efficiency of handling multiple connections.

In that case, what is the best configuration?

Comment: There ist no real answer to that because it depends on your available hardware .. assigning lots of real memory for indexes usually speeds things up. The fastest being the whole mysql setup running in memory.

Comment: Profile your tests to confirm that mysql takes a significant percentage of the time, and look at top or whatever to see what mysql is doing when your tests are running (on my laptop, it's not waiting for the disk!), and add that data to the question.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on test database setup.

If the database is running all the time, you'll have to tweak settings like buffer sizes and io threads. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905535/5166812) suggests, there are tools that can test and produce recommandations for your server setup.

In unit tests where data integrity isn't that important, you can use in memory tables (ENGINE=MEMORY) and disable INNODB's double write (innodb_doublewrite=OFF). This will reduce data integrity but increase performance.

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/stumpdk/MySql.Server) for setting up a the database every time the tests are run.
By using these settings, the database are running in about a second:

- innodb_fast_shutdown=2 (fast shut down)
- innodb_log_file_size=1048576 (smallest possible log
  size)
- innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
  (smallest possible data file sizes for quicker startup)

Comment: > innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend

this didn't work on my machine (5.6)

Comment: While these are good config settings, one of the big improvements we found was disabling innodb_file_per_table (which defaults to on past MySQL 5.5 I believe). When creating a lot of tables, it can making creating a table up to 4 times faster, which added up to quite a lot of time saved for our 200 plus tables. As with anything, test it with your specific testing needs.

Comment: @EnthusiasticProgrammer Thank you for this, I can also confirm that disabling `innodb_file_per_table` massively speeds up CREATE TABLE statements, in my case about 3x.